# what happens with strcat and statically allocated character arrays?

Tags: c, static

I found this in some legacy code.

```
static char title1[] = "SUMMARY REPORT";
static char title2[] = "PERIOD: ";

...

strcat(title2, "10/10/2011");
```

This strcat operation results in title1 being overwritten with part of the date string. I was able to reproduce this in a small program, but not with static arrays. I looked at the memory location in the legacy code and the title2 buffer is located just prior to title1. The fix was simple, I just added a length to title2 (which pushed the start of title1 further in memory) to hold the entire date. Why is title2 behind title1 in memory? This is on a SPARC, btw.

Comment: `title2` comes behind `title1` because the compiler put it there. The standard doesn't specify memory layout, and the compiler is free to do it in any order that is easiest for the compiler writers.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is title2 behind title1 in memory?

Why not? The standard makes no guarantees on where will the objects lay. The code you show is fundamentally wrong. `strcat` destination should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's **fundamentally** wrong but logically wrong. strcat dest is a C string; it's just not long enough.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: I would still say meeting function preconditions is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` assumes the buffer you pass in is large enough to hold the concatenated string, and it will overwrite over the end of your buffer if it's too small. So whatever behind your buffer gets overwritten.